# ArticleTitle returns NULL in R RISmed when not in english

Tags: r, package, pubmed

I've been using RISmed package but, when some article has ArticleTitle in another language (inside pubmed appears between square brackets), the R package returns NULL.
Do you know any way to circumvent this issue?
Many Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an ID of an article which fails to give you a title?

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce this behavior and cannot repeat it in a manner that allows me to detect a pattern. Nevertheless, still obtaining empty titles. For example, after executing the query "benznidazole or nifurtimox" obtained 1559 ids. After fetching using EUtilsSummary, extracted titles with ArticleTitle but, 13 of them were "NA" values. The list of IDs is: "29563916,29491856,29255475,29203486,29203485,29107428,28989779,28824880,28749767,28620619,28242662,27688600,28889902"
Hope can help.